# Read embedded file from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have to pass the path of a config file to a framework method (Gurok SmartInspect). The config file is an embedded resource of the assembly. Currently I read the file from the assembly and store it outside and then pass the pathName. Is there a better / less complicated way to achieve this goal, without copying the file?

```
    private static void ConfigLogger()
    {
        const string embeddedFileName = "xxx.SmartInspect.properties";
        const string configFileName = "SmartInspect.properties";
        ExtractFileFromAssembly(embeddedFileName, configFileName);
        SiAuto.Si.LoadConfiguration(configFileName);
    }

    private static void ExtractFileFromAssembly(string assemblyFileName, string configFileName)
    {
        using (Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyFileName) )
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];
            int read = s.Read(buffer, 0, (int)s.Length);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(configFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only way that Gurok SmartInspect reads configuration information is from a file that you pass it a path to and you've decided to embed that file in your assembly, then yes, your method is fine. You might want to consider adding some exception handling but otherwise I see no problem with this.

Comment: thanks
yes the only possible way is to pass a path. So there is no shorthand method for extracting file from an assembly? or even a "path" to reach a file inside the assembly?