# How to create a new file from a FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream, fileinfo

I have a javascript file as an embedded resource in an assembly, and I'm trying to use the Stream from "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("someName");" to create a new FileInfo object. My confusion is how to use a stream to create the FileInfo. If anyone can help me in this I would be greatly appreciative. I'm sure it's probably something easy, but easy is usually what I always seem to miss.

Comment: @jhorton: You need to be more specific about what you are trying to do and why you need a FileInfo or believe one to be associated with your Stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the file, then read the resource stream, and write the file stream.

Comment: So then I want to create the new File using something like File.Create("pathToFolder"). Then use a Writer to write the stream to the file.

Comment: Or else just do your own inputStream.Read / outputStream.Write loop.

Comment: So to clarify after a successful write. I had to use a StreamReader for the EmbeddedResource stream, and a StreamWriter for the new FileStream. Very basic skills that have seemed to leaked out of my metaphorical cracked glass.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Because you have a Stream, and FileStream inherits from Stream, it doesn't mean that all Stream instances are FileStream instances (and by extension, have files that are the source of the Stream).

That being said, it doesn't make sense that the Stream returned from the call to 
GetManifestResourceStream would have a FileInfo associated with it, just like a NetworkStream wouldn't have a FileInfo instance associated with it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a FileInfo, then you'll probably have to copy the data from your embedded resource out to a file on the file system. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021857/read-embedded-file-from-assembly) has some sample code.